# Does Luffy have "Gomu Gomu no Jet Yari"?

Tags: one-piece

In Gear 2, 3 and 4, Luffy has several of his original attacks improved according to his respective gear forces.

- Gomu Gomu no Pistol is Jet Pistol in Gear 2nd, Elephant Pistol in Gear 3rd and Culverin in Gear 4th.
- Same goes for Bazooka, and without Gear 4, it stands for Gattling Gun as well.

These just mere examples, as he has quite a lot of attacks. I wouldn't even ask about all of them, so I'd like to focus on one absence I noticed.

Luffy has **Gomu Gomu no Yari** which appeared as **Rhino Schneider** in Gear 4. Does it have Gear 2 (and 3) versions?

Comment: I think it's possible but given that we've only seen gear 4 once so far we don't have enough info to draw that conclusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the anime: Gomu Gomu no Jet Lance was used against Blueno and was a Gear 2 attack.  Note that Lance is similar to a Spear which is what Yari refers to.

Gomu Gomu no Jet Spear was used after the timeskip against Monet as a Gear 2 version.

I am not aware of a Gear 3 version.

This is all from the [wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Gomu_Gomu_no_Mi/Gear_Third_Techniques).

Comment: Just to be clear a yari is a traditional Japanese spear weapon.